# Packery appended methods add three items. How to add one item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, packery

I'm try to add dynamically **packery** item by `click` method. All every thing is working fine except on a single click **packery** add ***three*** new items. My question is how to add one item on single click?

**[Method](http://packery.metafizzy.co/methods.html#appended)**

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/HFbia)**

Thanks.

**Edit**

After page load grid items is **Five**. See the picture below.

[image: Manually added items when page load first time]

When `click` the **Append items** `button` packery will add more **three** items. See the picture below.

[image: After click the Append items button]

**Snippet**

```js
var $grid = $('.grid').packery({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});

$('.append-button').on( 'click', function() {
  // create new item elements
  var $items = getItemElement().add( getItemElement() ).add( getItemElement() );
  // append elements to container
  $grid.append( $items )
    // add and lay out newly appended elements
    .packery( 'appended', $items );
});


// make <div class="grid-item grid-item--width# grid-item--height#" />
function getItemElement() {
  var $item = $('<div class="grid-item"></div>');
  // add width and height class
  var wRand = Math.random();
  var hRand = Math.random();
  var widthClass = wRand > 0.85 ? 'grid-item--width3' : wRand > 0.7 ? 'grid-item--width2' : '';
  var heightClass = hRand > 0.85 ? 'grid-item--height3' : hRand > 0.5 ? 'grid-item--height2' : '';
  $item.addClass( widthClass ).addClass( heightClass );
  return $item;
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
  background: #DDD;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .grid-item ---- */

.grid-item {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 80px;
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #C09;
  border: 2px solid hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
}

.grid-item--width2 { width: 160px; }
.grid-item--height2 { height: 160px; line-height: 160px; }

.grid-item--width3 { width: 240px; }
.grid-item--height3 { height: 240px; }

button { font-size: 20px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mfzy.co/packery.pkgd.js"></script>
<h1>Packery - appended</h1>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2">5</div>
</div>

<p><button class="append-button">Append items</button></p>
```

**My Question:**

How can I control append items? I want to add dynamically **one** item not **three** items on single `click`.

**Note:**

> Don't submit the down vote if you failed to submit solution for it.

Comment: SO isn't suitable for crowd-debugging. It is not clear, what is the point of your question.

Comment: This is simple. Did you see the demo or snippet? Please see the demo or snippet and try to click **Append items button**.

Comment: When I click Append items button packery add three items. I want to add one item only.

Comment: f.. Your snippet contains **three** `getItemElement`. change to one

Comment: Yes. It's by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what you trying todo in this line?

`var $items = getItemElement().add( getItemElement() ).add( getItemElement() );`

if you change it to this:

`var $items = getItemElement();`

only one element will be added.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PWXdvm)

Answer (score 4):

Strange question. Just remove two of elements out of the code.

```
var $items = getItemElement();
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egbLxQ

Comment: Thanks for ans and comments.

Comment: You are welcome, but you should debug by yourself next time before posting huge amount of codes-styles-html.